# is it possible to recognise virtual image instead of real image using ARKit ? (iOS 12)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I had done few AR Image tracking apps and AR World Tracking apps.

AR Image Tracking works on recognise the images on the physical map captured from camera.

is there any way to make AR Image Tracking to recognise the virtual "image" which basically is SCNPlane materials?

Would be appreciated if anyone can point me some direction or advice.

(**Note:** for this project, I use detection image on ARWorldTrackingConfiguration)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think probably yes, it is possible by adding content image(which you want to detect i.e in your map) to your Assets.xcassets. and then use this code to detect a virtual image like below:

// Put your image name in (withName: "namehere")

```
 lazy var mapNode: SCNNode = {
       let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "map", recursively: false)
        return node
    }()

// Now When detecting Images 


extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {

        func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor,
                    let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return }

                // TODO: Comment out code
                //            let planeNode = self.getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage: imageAnchor.referenceImage)
                //            planeNode.opacity = 0.0
                //            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
                //            planeNode.runAction(self.fadeAction)
                //            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

                // TODO: Overlay 3D Object
                let overlayNode = self.getNode(withImageName: imageName)
                overlayNode.opacity = 0
                overlayNode.position.y = 0.2
                overlayNode.runAction(self.fadeAndSpinAction)
                node.addChildNode(overlayNode)

                self.label.text = "Image detected: \"\(imageName)\""
            }
        }

        func getPlaneNode(withReferenceImage image: ARReferenceImage) -> SCNNode {
            let plane = SCNPlane(width: image.physicalSize.width,
                                 height: image.physicalSize.height)
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            return node
        }

        func getNode(withImageName name: String) -> SCNNode {
            var node = SCNNode()
            switch name {
            case "map":
                node = mapNode

            default:
                break
            }
            return node
        }

    }
```